# Dynamically add handler for a button click event

Tags: c#, events, click, handler

How can I add a handler for the  click event of every single generated button?

For example:

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.ID = "delete_" + i.ToString();

btn.Click += degerate
{
     callFunction(i);
};
```

Whenever I try pressing the button, it'll only affect calling the function for the last inserted click event. Any suggestions for a fix?

Comment: where are all the buttons? Can you enumerate through them via a loop or do you need to find them in the code first?

Comment: I dynamically create them through a loop

Comment: I'm thinking a foreach loop might be your friend here.

Comment: Could you show me an example since i'm stuck and out of ideas :P

Comment: You need to post more code to make it less guessing for those who you asking this

Answer (score 0):

Within the loop you used to declare your buttons, use the following snippet:

```
button.Click += new EventHandler(<funcName>);
```

Don't forget that "funcName" must match the EventHandle delegate.

Then all your buttons will share the same Event Code, but each event is bound to it's own button.

You can access all info of each button, by casting the **sender** as the specific object type you're using, for example:

```
Button btn = (Button)sender;
btn.ID = <new value>;
```

Comment: So I would be able to give a parameter within it?

Comment: With this particular EventHandler no. But all info you have within each button is preserved. If you're using WPF, I'd suggest using the Tag property store any other required information.

Answer (score 0):

If the code you have above all gets executed every time you want to add a click handler, you are creating a brand new button object each time. Because it is a totally new object, it knows nothing about the click handlers attached to older buttons.

Comment: On the other hand, if you have a foreach around that code, you could  be running into a modified closure issue. See [this link](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/Access+to+modified+closure) for more information on modified closure.